# Can't delete object in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I'm setting data in NSUserDefault to one call to other class like :

```
kPref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
[kPref setObject:dicOrder forKey:SEND_DATA];
```

And retrieving like :

```
NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[kPref dictionaryForKey:SEND_DATA] mutableCopy];
[arrayOrder addObject:temp];
```

Now i can not delete any object in temp from `arrayOrder`.

How can i access this NSMutableDictionary that coming from `kpref`
OR how to delete any object in dictionary.

**EDIT**

im removing it like :

```
   [[[[[arrayOrder objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:ORDER_Choice] valueForKey:str] mutableCopy] removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

and it return me same array.

Comment: what abot `[temp removeObjectForKey: @"A_KEY"];`

Comment: You're creating a mutable copy and removing something from it.  This doesn't change the original, which is still stored in the array.

Comment: Can you write dictionary which you want  to remove with its hierarchy?

Comment: What is `arrayOrder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all , I got the solution :

Using `archivedDataWithRootObject:dicOrder`       :

```
  [kPref setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dicOrder] forKey:SEND_DATA];
```

And `unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray` like :

```
NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray = [kPref objectForKey:SEND_DATA];
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];
```

Comment: What?  You are saying you cannot store a dictionary in `NSUserDefaults` unless you serialise it first?